# What is Proto-Semitic *x̣?

Tags: phonology, comparative-linguistics, semitic-languages, reconstruction, ejectives

In his Akkadian grammar (specifically the appendix on phonology), Huehnergard lists the following Proto-Semitic consonants:

[image: consonant table]

Most of this looks familiar to me. However, **x̣* caught me by surprise; I'm not used to an emphatic velar fricative being included. (Semitic is very much not my specialty, though, so I'm not very well-read on it; it's entirely possible that it's a mainstream thing that I just haven't come across before.)

Is this part of the mainstream consensus? And what is the evidence for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One page further (p. 587), Huehnergard gives as one of the changes from Proto-Semitic to Old Babylonian:

> Common Semitic **ḫ* and **x̣* merged to *ḫ* (Huehnergard 2003):
>      **ḫamisum* > *ḫamšum* ‘five’; **saḫānum* > *šaḫānum* ‘to be warm’;
>      **x̣apārum* > ḫepērum ‘to dig’; **rax̣āṣ́um* > *raḫāṣ́um* ‘to wash’.

The reference is to the author's '[Akkadian *ḫ* and West Semitic **ḥ*](https://www.academia.edu/234669/2003_Akkadian_%E1%B8%AB_and_West_Semitic_%E1%B8%A5)'; pp. 102–119 in Leonid Kogan, ed., *Studia Semitica*; Orientalia: Papers of the Oriental Institute, 3 (Alexander Militarev volume).

The background is that Akkadian lost *ḥ* (preserved in West Semitic, whence the traditional *ḫ*/*ḥ* distinction), and that *ḫ* corresponds to *ḫ* in West Semitic, while there are exceptions to this (where *ḫ* corresponds to *ḥ* in West Semitic). The numbers are as follows (p. 112):

> - Akkadian Ø corresponds to West Semitic **ḥ* in about 60 examples; there are in addition some 50 examples of Akkadian Ø with *a* > *e*, i.e., in which the earlier presence of either Proto-Semitic **ḥ* or Proto-Semitic *ʕ* is likely.
> - Akkadian *ḫ* corresponds to West Semitic **ḥ* in about 50 examples.
> - Akkadian *ḫ* corresponds to West Semitic *ḫ* in about 90 examples; there are also nearly 200 additional Akkadian roots with *ḫ* for which no West Semitic cognates are known.

The traditional solution is that Proto-Semitic *ḫ* stays unaffected, whereas Proto-Semitic **ḥ* is dropped in East Semitic. However, the second group, where West Semitic **ḥ* corresponds to East Semitic *ḫ*, is too large for this. In default of a phonological explanation that can predict which instances of **ḥ* become Ø and which become *ḫ*, we must posit a third consonant for this second group (Huehnergard compares this to the situation of *ð* merging with *d* in Aramaic but *z* in Hebrew; cf. Aramaic *dkr* vs. Hebrew *zkr* 'remember').

Because this hypothetical consonant merged with *ḫ* and *ḥ* it should be a fricative articulated near the velum or pharynx. Most consonants in Proto-Semitic come in a triadic opposition (voiced/voiceless/emphatic), the exceptions being bilabials and velar and pharyngeal fricatives (none of which have emphatics). Because a emphatic pharyngeal fricative is 'unexpected on articulatory grounds' (p. 115), an emphatic velar fricative *x̣* is proposed, i.e., IPA [x'].

We then get (p. 116):

- Proto-Semitic *ḥ* is unaffected in West Semitic but dropped in East Semitic.
- Proto-Semitic *ḫ* is unaffected throughout.
- Proto-Semitic *x̣* becomes *ḥ* in West Semitic and *ḫ* in East Semitic.

Is this the mainstream consensus? I can't really comment since I don't work in phonology, but I can say that (1) you are right to be surprised (2003 is pretty recent) and (2) Huehnergard is usually right.

Comment: The other possibility is that at least some of the words with ḥ in West Semitic and ḫ in East Semitic are in fact loanwords in the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Today´s consensus is that the emphatic sounds were realized as glottalized (as, e.g., in Akkadian), not as pharyngalized (cf., e.g., Arabic). Therefore, one for a root, no more (in Akkadian, known as the Geers´ Law). The problem with Huehnergard´s theory (as I see it) is that it reconstructs/creates quite a lot of roots with two emphatic radicals in his reconstruction of, say, Protoakkadian. OK, perhaps we can postulate that it was a retention from another stage (between Protosemitic and Protoakkadian?; H. self was playing with many additional stages in his reconstruction of the history of Aramaic), but it violates the language economy. I do not see an elegant way out of this "Huehnergards´ paradox". Perhaps we should expect another secondary articulation for this velar fricative?